# WHAT OPERATOR TO BE USE IN THIS STATEMENT?

Tags: mysql

**Display Phillip and Kenwood products which SellingPrice is more than 300.**

ive tried to put two AND on this single statement,and then nothing works on the mysql.It just display empty set.

```
mysql> select name, sellingprice from product 
where name LIKE '%Kenwood%' AND '%Phillip%' AND sellingprice > 300;
```

Comment: The problem you're having is that you're trying to transliterate the English directly to logic, which doesn't always work. When it says, "Display Phillip and Kenwood products...", if you think about it, it really means you want to display a product if it's name is "Phillip" OR it's name is "Kenwood". Obviously, no product can have it's name be both simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely that a product will be from Kenwood AND Phillip.
You're looking for 'OR' ... or 'IN'.

```
select name, sellingprice from product where ( name LIKE '%Kenwood%' OR name LIKE '%Phillip%' ) AND sellingprice > 300;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `name LIKE '%Kenwood%' AND '%Phillip%'`.

You can do `name LIKE '%Kenwood%' AND name LIKE '%Phillip%'`, though.

Answer (score 1):

the LIKE needs to be repeated.

From the context of the example data, you also probably want OR, not AND ... (Just that it's unlikely you'l have products made by two competing manufacturers)

```
mysql> select name, sellingprice from product 
where (name LIKE '%Kenwood%' OR name LIKE '%Phillip%' ) AND sellingprice > 300;
```

or

```
mysql> select name, sellingprice from product 
where name LIKE '%Kenwood%' AND name LIKE '%Phillip%' AND sellingprice > 300;
```

If you really wanted AND

Comment: `where name LIKE '%Kenwood%' AND name LIKE '%Phillip%'...` This will select out products that have both `Kenwood` and `Phillip` somewhere in their name.